# How to declare a variable with two types in Kotlin, like val x: Int or String

Tags: types, kotlin

I'm gonna write a method like:

```
object UIBehavior {
   fun dialog(context: Context, title: Int | String, message: Int | String){
     val dialogObj = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
     dialogObj.setTitle(title)
     dialogObj.setMessage(message)
   }
}
```

The methods *dialogObj.setTitle* and *dialogObj.setMessage* allow two types of parameters, and how can I delare the parameter that can let the method *dialog* allow only two types Int and String?

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. It might be easier to write 2 fun signatures that both call another fun that does the dialog stuff

Comment: If you are familiar with Scala's Either, than you can use this implementation for Kotlin https://github.com/adelnizamutdinov/kotlin-either

Comment: `setTitle(Int)` and `setTitile(String)` are actually two different methods that happen to share the same name. What you propose would be ambiguous because it would have to call different methods depending on what you call it with.

Comment: A solution using Generics, Sealed classes and when expression for sealed class. Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74566114/6269691

Answer (score 15):

You can't do that in Kotlin.

But you can have multiple versions of a function, e.g.

```
object UIBehavior {
    fun dialog(context: Context, titleId: Int, messageId: Int){
        val titleString = context.getString(titleId)
        val messageString = context.getString(messageId)
        dialog(context, titleString, messageString)
    }

    fun dialog(context: Context, title: String, message: String) {
        val dialogObj = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        dialogObj.setTitle(title)
        dialogObj.setMessage(message)
    }
}
```

That way you can simply call the function with either ids or strings and it looks like you are using the same function

```
UIBehavior.dialog(this, R.string.title, R.string.message)
UIBehavior.dialog(this, "title", "message")
```

You could also use a common supertype of `Int` and `String` but that would allow a lot more and I wouldn't recommend that.

```
fun dialog(context: Context, title: Any, messageId: Any){
    val titleString = when (title) {
        is String -> title
        is Int -> context.getString(title)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type")
    }
    val messageString = when ...
       ...
    dialog(context, titleString, messageString)
}
```

Generics don't work here either because you can't call `dialogObj.setTitle(title)` dynamically. It must be known at compile time whether you want to call the `Int` or the `String` overload of that function. It's also not really different from using `Any`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Generics can be the solution for you.

```
fun <T>dialog(context: Context, title: T, message: T){
   if(title !is String && title !is Int) throw InvalidParameterException()
   val dialogObj = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
   dialogObj.setTitle(title)
   dialogObj.setMessage(message)
}
```

2. Also using Any can be a solution too:

```
fun dialog(context: Context, title: Any, message: Any){
   if(title !is String && title !is Int) throw InvalidParameterException()
   val dialogObj = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
   dialogObj.setTitle(title)
   dialogObj.setMessage(message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) to have the same method, and check the type in the method body.

Or have two different methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Any, but I don't think it is a very nice solution at all.

It would be much better to make both the title and message a String or CharSequence in line with the types setTitle and setMessage take as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I was writing codes

```
interface DialogOption {
    val title: Any
    val message: Any
    val positiveBtnTxt: Any
    val negativeBtnTxt: Any
    fun confirm(d: DialogInterface, n: Int) {
        d.dismiss()
    }
    fun cancel(d: DialogInterface, n: Int) {
        d.dismiss()
    }

}

object UIBehavior {
    fun dialog(context: Context, opt: DialogOption) {
        val dialogObj = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        val title = opt.title
        val message = opt.message
        val poTxt = opt.positiveBtnTxt
        val negTxt = opt.negativeBtnTxt
        fun positiveCallback(d: DialogInterface, n: Int) {
            opt.confirm(d, n)
        }

        fun negativeCallback(d: DialogInterface, n: Int) {
            opt.cancel(d, n)
        }

        if (title is String) {
            dialogObj.setTitle(title)
        } else if (title is Int) {
            dialogObj.setTitle(title)
        }
        if (message is String) {
            dialogObj.setMessage(message)
        } else if (message is Int) {
            dialogObj.setMessage(message)
        }
        if (poTxt is String) {
            dialogObj.setPositiveButton(poTxt, ::positiveCallback)
        } else if (poTxt is Int) {
            dialogObj.setPositiveButton(poTxt, ::positiveCallback)
        }
        if ( negTxt is String) {
            dialogObj.setNegativeButton(negTxt, ::negativeCallback)
        } else if (negTxt is Int) {
            dialogObj.setNegativeButton(negTxt, ::negativeCallback)
        }

        dialogObj.show()
    }
}
```

It works but not sure if it's reasonable

Answer (score 0):

## Solution :

---

We can declare a **variable with multiple types** in Kotlin by combining :

1. **Generics**,
2. [**Sealed** classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html) and
3. [**when** expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html#sealed-classes-and-when-expression) for sealed class.

---

### Code Example :

```
sealed class ABClass<out T>
{
    data class SealedClassA<out ClassA>(val value: ClassA) : ABClass<ClassA>()
    data class SealedClassB<out ClassB>(val value: ClassB) : ABClass<ClassB>()
}

fun main() {

    val a : ClassA = ClassA()
    var b : ClassB = ClassB()
    var s : String = "Just a string"

    var c : ABClass<Any> = ABClass.SealedClassA(a)
        c = ABClass.SealedClassB(b) // Works

        c = ABClass()               // Error : Sealed types cannot be instantiated
        c = ABClass.SealedClassA(s) // Error : class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class Token
        c = ABClass.SealedClassB(s) // Error : class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class Break

    when(c)
    {
        is ABClass.SealedClassA -> { println("ABClassClassA ${(c.value as ClassA).AVariable}") }
        is ABClass.SealedClassB -> { println("ABClassClassB ${(c.value as ClassB).BVariable}") }
    }

}

open class ClassA
{
    var AVariable : Int = 1
}
open class ClassB
{
    var BVariable : Int = 10
}
```

## Explanation:

Sealed class `ABClass` has generic type `T`.

The subsequent direct **subclasses** (SealedClassA & SealedClassB) of the sealed class  are restricted to only be :

`ClassA` for `data class SealedClassA` or
`ClassB` for `data class SealedClassB`

Thus constraining to type : ClassA or ClassB.

### Composite class Definition

```
sealed class ABClass<out T>
{
    data class SealedClassA<out ClassA>(val value: ClassA) : ABClass<ClassA>()
    data class SealedClassB<out ClassB>(val value: ClassB) : ABClass<ClassB>()
}
```

### Usage Definition

```
var c : ABClass<Any>
```

**`Any`** allows to store any type variable. But due to the definition of the sealed class only `ClassA` or `ClassB` types is allowed, others will give error thus putting constraint the type.

### Allowed

```
c = ABClass.SealedClassA(a)
c = ABClass.SealedClassB(b)
```

### Not Allowed

```
c = ABClass()               // Error : Sealed types cannot be instantiated
c = ABClass.SealedClassA(s) // Error : class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class Token
c = ABClass.SealedClassB(s) // Error : class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class Break
```

### Using the when expression.

It's possible to verify all cases, and **else clause** is **not required.**

```
when(c)
{
    is ABClass.SealedClassA -> { println("ABClassClassA ${(c.value as ClassA).AVariable}") }
    is ABClass.SealedClassB -> { println("ABClassClassB ${(c.value as ClassB).BVariable}") }
}
```

### Result

Variable `c` can store essentially only two types `ClassA` and `ClassB`.