# how to create a type that may contain Int or String

Tags: python, kotlin, polymorphism

If there's a function `f(x)`, and x's type may be Int or String,
if it's Int, then this f will return `x+1`
if it's String, then f will reverse x and return it.

This is easy in dynamic typed languages like python and javascript which
just uses `isinstance(x, Int)`.

We can know its type and do something with if-else,
but in static type languages like kotlin, I don't know how to do that?
Because I don't know how to make x has a type that may be Int or String.

def f(x):

```
 if isinstance(x, int):
     return x+1
 if isinstance(x, str):

     return x[::-1]
```

in haskell, we have pattern matching to do that

f :: Either Int String -> Either Int String

f (Left x) = Left (x+1)

f (Right x) = Right (reverse x)

and in kotlin?

Comment: Hi John, It is not possible, Please check this similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52736927/4862126

Comment: Could you use an overload? Create two overloads of the function, one which takes in an `Int` and one that takes in a `String`, and implement each one accordingly? Obviously `x` itself at the call site could never be "Int or String" as Kotlin doesn't have union types or something like that (unless you want to declare it as `any`, which wouldn't really be a good idea as then it could be **any** type). But if you know at the call site at compile time whether `x` is `Int` or `String` then overloads might be the way to go as the right overload will be called based on the type of `x`.

Comment: Just define the function as taking a parameter of type Any.  You can then test what the actual type the object is inside the function.  The referenced "duplicate" asks a different question.  It asks how to define a variable with two types.  THAT is something you can't do.  The obvious solution here doesn't require that.  Any is just a single type.  Just define the parameter as an Any.

Comment: Or you can check generics

Comment: You can also define a single type of your own that can contain either a String or an Int,.  Maybe call it StringOrInt?  Then again you are dealing with a single type, and that type can internally handle having two modes, one where it represents an Int and a second where it represents a String.

Comment: There are ways using an `Either` type, or bypassing type-checking entirely using `Any`.  But you lose the security, efficiency, and maintainability of strong static type-checking.  I'd recommend rethinking your approach a little.  Can you have two separate functions?  (They can have the same name, as long as they take different parameter types.)

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you have [Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/) that provides a lot of functional capabilities to the language. Between them you have [`EitherT`](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/arrow/data/eithert/). 
That lets you define:

```
fun f(x: Either<Int, String>): Either<Int, String> =
    x.bimap({ it+1 }, { it.reversed() })
```

Answer (score 0):

sealed class E

data class L(val v: String) : E()

data class R(val v: Int): E()

fun poly(expr: E):E  = when(expr) {

```
is L -> L(expr.v)

is R -> R(expr.v + 1)
```

}

println(poly(poly(R(3))))

println(poly(L("aha")))

fun poly2(expr: E):Any?  = when(expr) {

```
is L -> expr.v

is R -> expr.v + 1
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like:

```
fun getValue(id: Int): Any { ... } 

fun process(value: Int) { ... } 
fun process(value: String) { ... }
val value = getValue(valueId)
 when (value) { 
is Int -> process(value)
is String -> process(value)
else -> ... }
```

This way, you can use method overloading to do the job for you based on params.